# JTDS and JBOSS JDBC Connection Pool Problem, any solution? Maybe a custom ValidConnectionChecker?

Tags: jdbc, jboss, jtds

I'm facing a weird production problem. Environment is the following:

- JBOSS 4.0.2
- SQL Server 2005
- Driver JTDS 1.2.5

From time to time the following szenario occurs.

A SQL command fails to Excute with

```
 java.sql.SQLException: I/O Error: Read timed out
```

(I can live with that, if it just happens twice a day or so)

But from that moment on the connection seems to be wasted without the pool recognizing it, as I continously receive

```
java.sql.SQLException: Invalid state, the Connection object is closed.
```

from that moment on. The only thing that helps is restarting JBOSS. This occurs despite of the fact that I have

```
 <check-valid-connection-sql>select getdate()</check-valid-connection-sql>
```

set up in my Datasource definition.

I was wondering if I can use a custom ValidConnectionChecker, that either rebuilds the connection itself, or explicitly throws a Exception to fix this. Maybe anyone has other suggestions.

Here is my complete DS definition.

```
  <local-tx-datasource>
    <jndi-name>MyDS</jndi-name>
    <connection-url>jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://192.168.35.235:1433/MyDb;user=user1;password=pwd;appName=MyApp;loginTimeout=15;socketTimeout=120</connection-url>
    <driver-class>net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver</driver-class>
    <user-name>user1</user-name>
    <password>pwd</password>
    <min-pool-size>10</min-pool-size>
    <max-pool-size>25</max-pool-size>
    <blocking-timeout-millis>60000</blocking-timeout-millis>
    <idle-timeout-minutes>1</idle-timeout-minutes>
    <check-valid-connection-sql>select getdate()</check-valid-connection-sql>
  </local-tx-datasource>
```

Any help appriciated.

Regards

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try changing your driver class line to
net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbcx.JtdsDataSource.
net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver doesn't implement the javax.sql.ConnectionPoolDataSource interface.
source:
http://jtds.sourceforge.net/faq.html#features

Comment: Is this possible? Can you really use a DataSource in place of a Driver in JBoss?

Answer (score 3):

Probably too late the solution, but I am stuck with the jtds driver here. Hope this saves half an hour of your productive time.

The fix is to specify a validationQuery to the Apache dbcp2 Connection Pool implementation. 
For jtds/sql server 
I specified the spring configuration as follows:

```
<bean id="sqlServerDS" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp2.BasicDataSource" destroy-method="close" >
    <property name="driverClassName" value="${jdbc.driverClassName}" />
    <property name="url" value="${jdbc.url}" />
    <property name="username" value="${jdbc.username}" />
    <property name="password" value="${jdbc.password}" />
    <property name="defaultReadOnly" value="true" />
    <property name="validationQuery" value="select 1" />
</bean>
```

In case you are not using Spring, call setValidationQuery method on BasicDataSource in your java code.

```
BasicDataSource bds = new BasicDataSource();
bds.setValidationQuery("select 1");
```

Answer (score 0):

`Connection.isValid()` isn't implemented in JTDS.
I found even catching the exception and forcing a complete restart of the connection didn't work.