# SQL Server connection in Wildfly using JTDS driver

Tags: sql-server, jakarta-ee, jboss, wildfly, jtds

**What is the correct way to setup a SQL Server datasource on Widlfly?**

I need to access a SQL Server database from my web application which runs on Wildfly.

I have setup the datasource as follows:

```
<datasource jta="false" jndi-name="java:jboss/db" pool-name="db" enabled="true" use-ccm="false">
    <connection-url>jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://IP_ADDRESS;instance=SQLEXPRESS;DatabaseName=DB</connection-url>
    <driver-class>net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver</driver-class>
    <driver>jtds-1.3.1.jar</driver>
</datasource>
```

This works fine except that when the SQL Server is restarted, the connection is lost and the datasource doesn't manage to recreate one. So I get errors like:

> Invalid state, the Connection object is closed.

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25612318/829571) suggests adding some validation, so I did this:

```
<validation>
    <check-valid-connection-sql>SELECT 1</check-valid-connection-sql>
    <validate-on-match>false</validate-on-match>
    <background-validation>false</background-validation>
</validation>
```

But that does not solve the problem and I still get the same "connection closed" error from time to time.

[This other post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3986603/829571) suggests using a DataSource instead of a Driver, so I have added this to my configuration:

```
    <datasource-class>net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbcx.JtdsDataSource</datasource-class>
```

But when I test the connection I get an exception:

> java.sql.SQLException: The serverName property has not been set.
>           at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbcx.JtdsDataSource.getConnection(JtdsDataSource.java:150)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was having the same issue after migrating to WFLY and resolved it by adding the  properties.

This is what my complete *-ds.xml looks like:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <datasources xmlns="http://www.jboss.org/ironjacamar/schema">
  <datasource jndi-name="java:/xxxDS" pool-name="MSSQL">
     <connection-url>
     jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;database=dbname;charset=UTF-8
     </connection-url>
     <driver>sqljdbc</driver>
     <security>
        <user-name>xxx</user-name>
        <password>xxx</password>
     </security>
     <pool>
        <!-- default is 0 -->
        <min-pool-size>10</min-pool-size>
        <!-- default is 20 -->
        <max-pool-size>50</max-pool-size>
     </pool>
     <validation>
        <valid-connection-checker 
        class-name="org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.extensions.mssql.MSSQLValidConnectionChecker" />
        <validate-on-match>false</validate-on-match>
        <background-validation>true</background-validation>
        <check-valid-connection-sql>select 1</check-valid-connection-sql>
        <background-validation-millis>10000</background-validation-millis>
     </validation>
  </datasource>
```

For me, the valid-connection-checker was not adequate, but by adding the background validation with select 1 it was working.

We have moved over to using the jdbc driver directly from MSFT however:

```
<driver name="sqljdbc" module="mc.jdbc.sqljdbc">
  <driver-class>com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver</driver-class>
</driver>
```

That also might make a difference, however we had it set up with JBoss AS7 and the jdts driver for a long time.